# SQL Select issue with PHP

Tags: php, sql, select

My site is successfully inserting date from values the user has entered, however, when it comes to getting data from the database I have a problem.

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT cost FROM settings LIMIT 1";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    $cost = $sql;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

I'm just getting an error (Error: SELECT cost FROM settings LIMIT 1) and I'm unsure how to identify the problem. Everything looks correct from my point of view, obviously it's not.

Comment: What is `$conn->error` giving??

Comment: What error are you getting over here?

Comment: Okay, I made some changes and have pasted the full page of code at http://paste.ofcode.org/fMaEaKeKJqrbTp3bYgXgRB. I'm getting nothing for $conn->error other than 'SELECT cost FROM settings LIMIT 1'. Cost is happening in the 'get_cost' function

Comment: I seen your code but I cannot find connection establishment statement at anywhere in your code.. First check the connection is established or not

Comment: I'm passing $conn as a parameter which comes from the file connect.php. It's connecting successfully

Comment: Its because you've not having a successful connection you need to include your `connect.php` file code within your code by `extending` its class or creating a `trait` and using that within your class

Comment: I'm probably doing this wrong, but in my file that includes all the HTML I've  got     <?php 
    include 'database/connect.php';
    include 'php/check_booking.php';
    ?>. You're probably right that this should be changed, but it isn't the root of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. This code works only if you have properly connected to DB.

```
$sql = "SELECT `cost` FROM `settings` LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["cost"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using backtics,

```
$sql = "SELECT `cost` FROM `settings` LIMIT 1";
```

And also,

```
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    .....
```

Comment: And where is `$conn` declared in your code?? Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` see if you get any error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error is in.
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
    }

$conn->query($sql) will not return TRUE for SELECT QUERY ,it will return a result object. So the condition becomes false and you are getting the else part printed.